# Button enabled every 60 days in Swift 4

Tags: time, nsdate, userdefaults

---

Hi everyone, I need to create a button thet is enabled every 60 days, I created it but it's working only if the app is running or in background, how can I make it work eaven when the app it's closed and opened again?

here is what I did sofar:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var questBtn: UIButton!

func enableButton() {
    self.questBtn.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func questBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    self.questBtn.isEnabled = false
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5185000, target: self, selector: Selector(("enableButton")), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

I found a solution here but I am a vry biginner and there was no code example
I hope you can help me.
Thankyou

Comment: Use a db, store the last time the button was available, once your user launch your app count the difference between the stored and the current date, if the difference is over 60 days then the button become available again, you replace the date stored by the current one and you repeat.

Comment: thankyou for the answer, how can I do that? have you an example?